# qtsinglecoreapplication aboutToClose()

Tags: qt

I have this piece of code. I need to catch the event when my program is about to close, but I cant make that the slot gets called.

```
QtSingleCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
if(app.isRunning()){
  return 0;
}else{
  MyClass mainClass;
    QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),
                     &mainClass, SLOT(aboutToQuit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

QtSingleCoreApplication inherits from QCoreApplication

Comment: We cannot see MyClass declaration from this example.

Comment: how do you quit this application? is there a `quit` call somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `MyClass` a separate `QObject` class, why don't you inherit it directly from `QtSingleCoreApplication`. That way, you can catch the signal before the whole signal/slot mechanism is shut down.

```
class MyApplication : public QtSingleCoreApplication {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyApplication(int argc, char **argv) : QtSingleCoreApplication(argc, argv) {
        connect(this, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, this, &MyApplication::cleanupApplication);
    }

public slots:
    void cleanupApplication();
};

void MyApplication::cleanupApplication(){
    // do something important
}

void main(int argc, char **argv){
    MyApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.isRunning() ? 0 : app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that aproach didnt work for me.